# Angular - How to add click event handler to dynamically added content

Tags: angular

I have  a requirement to populate content dynamically in angular (not angualar js). 
And that dynamic content would contain links, I need to find the link clicked and extract some property value from that clicked link and use that for processing. Angular does not seem to be supporting this.

let me show what a dynamic message would contain..

component template snippet as below

```
<div [innerHTML]="some_html_content"></div>
```

some_html_content would contain value like below

```
some_html_content =    'please make you selection <a onClik="navigate()" some-prop="somevalue-1">Click Link 1 </a>
    <a onClik="navigate()" some-prop="somevalue-2">Click Link 2 </a>';
```

Please  help me find a solution which works for angular.

Comment: if its angular 2+, use `(click)` event listener.

Comment: instead of onClik use (click) and try it

Comment: you can do this with the renderer2 service. but this is generally a bad idea altogether, and suggests that your approach isn't very angular

Answer (score 0):

Due to security concerns, Angular does not process HTML added by `[innerHTML]`. This means that `innerHTML` content will not respond to events.

## Workaround with `*ngFor`

Although `innerHTML` doesn't work, you can still dynamically insert HTML that responds to `click` events using `*ngFor`.

#### ExampleComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.scss']
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {

  public links: Array<{ linkName: string, method: ()=>void }>;

  public constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.links = [];
    this.links.push({ linkName: 'Link 1', method: this.navigate });
    this.links.push({ linkName: 'Link 2', method: this.navigate });
  }

  public navigate = () => {
    alert('navigate() clicked!');
    this.router.navigate(['your-url-here']);
  }
}
```

**Note:** The `navigate()` method uses the arrow notation to create a closure, which captures the value of `this` for the injected `router`.

#### example.component.html

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let link of links">
    <a (click)="link.method()" some-prop="somevalue-2">{{link.linkName}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

### Footnote about DomSanitizer (WARNING: This does not work.)

It is possible to add the original HTML via `innerHTML` using the Angular `DomSanitizer`, however, it will not execute the `(click)` event handler.

```
public html_links: SafeHtml;

public constructor(private router: Router, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

ngOnInit() {
  // DOES NOT WORK
  const some_html_content = `Please make your selection<br/><a (click)="navigate()">Link 1</a>
      <br/><a (click)="navigate()">Link 2</a>`;
  this.html_links = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(some_html_content);
}
```

#### Template

```
<div [innerHTML]="html_links"></div>
```